# Path-analyzer report for wildcard items

Tags: path-analyzer, wildcards

Sitecore: 9.1 + JSS 11 - Integrated mode

Module: Path analyzer

Issue:
We are using wild-card functionality to render certain pages in our application.
In the path-analyzer report, we are seeing '*' (aestrik) under '**Name**', not the name of the item to which the request had been resolved.

Are we missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, Sitecore does not provide a solution for Wildcard pages and the related tools (Analytics Tracking, Path Analyzer, and so on).

You need to implement a custom solution for correctly instructing Sitecore what your Wildcard matches.

I am not sure if this code can run on Sitecore 9.1 (it is for 8.x), but it should give you a place to start.

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Web;
using System;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker;

namespace Someproject.Pipelines.InitializeTracker
{
    public class CustomCreatePage : InitializeTrackerProcessor
    {
        private void CreateAndInitializePage(HttpContextBase httpContext, CurrentInteraction visit)
        {
            IPageContext empty = visit.CreatePage();
            empty.SetUrl(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
            DeviceItem device = Context.Device;
            if (device == null)
            {
                empty.SitecoreDevice.Id = Guid.Empty;
                empty.SitecoreDevice.Name = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                empty.SitecoreDevice.Id = device.ID.Guid;
                empty.SitecoreDevice.Name = device.Name;
            }

            // Default Sitecore implementation
            Item item = Context.Item;

            // Our logic starts here: if the current item is a wildcard
            if (item != null && item.Name == "*")
            {
                // Perform a call to the logic which resolves the correct item
                var resolvedItem = this.ResolveWildcardItem(item);

                if (resolvedItem != null)
                {
                    item = resolvedItem;
                }
            }

            // Resume the default behaviour
            if (item == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            empty.SetItemProperties(item.ID.Guid, item.Language.Name, item.Version.Number);
        }

        public override void Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
            if (args.IsSessionEnd)
            {
                return;
            }
            HttpContextBase httpContext = args.HttpContext;
            if (httpContext == null)
            {
                args.AbortPipeline();
                return;
            }
            this.CreateAndInitializePage(httpContext, args.Session.Interaction);
        }

        private Item ResolveWildcardItem(Item item)
        {
            return Someproject.BusinessLogic.AbstactedData.GetDataSource(item, Someproject.BusinessLogic.SlugFactory.GetSlugPreSelected(item));
        }
    }
}
```

The code would need to be patched in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns :patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig /" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <initializeTracker>
        <processor type="Someproject.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.CustomCreatePage,Someproject"            patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.CreatePage, Sitecore.Analytics']" />
      </initializeTracker>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Sources:

- https://lostinsitecore.com/2018/02/03/sitecore-wildcard-design-pattern-and-profile-cards/
- https://www.suneco.nl/blogs/track-the-correct-wildcard-item